# How to get records from the database by relation latest created record where has many in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have two database tables "inventory" and "inventory_sale_records". Products can have many sale records. I need to get all products from the database only by the latest created_at sale record, I don't need any other sell record that has been made before the last sale.

Here are my models:

Inventory model

```
public function sellRecord(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Inventory\SellRecord', 'product_id');
    }
```

SellRecords model:

```
public function inventory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Inventory\Inventory', 'id');
    }
```

How can I get all products from the inventory table sorted only by the latest sale record date in inventory_sell_records from the database?

I am also adding screenshots of both table's structure.

This is "inventory" table
[image]

This is "inventory_sell_records" table:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add screenshots of both table structure with record? Also, explain a bit more about the expected end result.

Comment: @RohitMittal , Sure! I just added two screenshots of both table.

I need to get all products from the inventory table. But these products need to be sorted by created_at date of the sale meaning by created_at from "inventory_sell_records" by the last added sale record.

Comment: "I don't need any other sell record that has been made before the last sale", "How can I get all products from the inventory table sorted only by the latest sale record date in inventory_sell_records from the database", I don't understand the questions are you looking for products that are on the latest sale report or are you looking to sort something based on eager loaded model?

Comment: @fake97 I need to get products by the latest sale.